# Генерирует ли компилятор конструктор копирования при побитовой инициализации ?

Tags: конструктор, c++

В книге Липпмана, ст 39 "inside C++ object model" написано.

> In the following program fragment:
>
> ```
> #include "Word.h"
> Word noun( "block" );
> void foo()
> {
> Word verb = noun;
> // ...
> }
> ```
>
> it is clear that verb is initialized
> with noun. But without looking at the
> declaration of class Word, it is not
> possible to predict the program
> behavior of that initialization. If
> the designer of class Word defines a
> copy constructor, the initialization
> of verb invokes it. If, however, the
> class is without an explicit copy
> constructor, the invocation of a
> compiler-synthesized instance depends
> on whether the class exhibits bitwise
> copy semantics. For example, given the
> following declaration of class Word:
>
> ```
> // declaration exhibits bitwise copy semantics
> class Word {
> public:
> Word( const char* );
> ~Word() { delete [] str; }
> // ...
> private:
> int
> cnt;
> char *str;
> };
> ```
>
> **a default copy constructor need not be synthesized, since the declaration
> exhibits bitwise copy semantics, and
> the initialization of verb need not
> result in a function call.**

Обратите внимания не последнюю строчку, насколько я понимаю там говорится что в этом случае компилятором не генерируется конструктор копирования, поскольку класс имеет побитовую семантику. Но как может делатся побитовое копирование без конструктора копирования, не должен ли тут компилятор генерировать конструктор копирования ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Но как может делатся побитовое копирование без конструктора копирования

`memcpy`, например

```
A a1;
A a2;

memcpy(&a2, &a1, sizeof(a1));
```

`copy ctor` может быть не сгенерирован т.к. класс содержит только POD-типы, а потому может быть безопасно скопирован через побитовое копирование

Comment: Может быть скопирован — да, но безопасно? Копирование указателя не очень-то безопасно.

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, то исходный вопрос не про поверхностные или глубокие копии и их отношения с указателями, а про метод копирования POD-структур.

Comment: @fogbit: вы правы, я придираюсь лишь к слову «безопасно». (В данном случае это приведёт к падению программы.)

Comment: @VladD: да, я прав. Вы предираетесь.

Answer (score 4):

В дополнение к ответу [[@fogbit](/users/2654/fogbit)](/users/2654/fogbit) приведу цитаты из документации:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization:

```
Syntax

T object = other ;  (1)
```

> If `T` is a class type and the type of other is cv-unqualified version of `T` or a class derived from `T`, the constructors of `T` are examined and the best match is selected by overload resolution. The constructor is then called to initialize the object.

Это значит, что будет использован наиболее подходящий конструктор. Поскольку явно определённый конструктор не подходит, будет использован неявно созданный конструктор копирования.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor:

> **Implicitly-defined copy constructor**
>
> If the implicitly-declared copy constructor is not deleted or trivial, it is defined (that is, a function body is generated and compiled) by the compiler. [...] For non-union class types (class and struct), the constructor performs full member-wise copy of the object's bases and non-static members, in their initialization order, using *direct initialization*.

Это значит, что будет выполнено почленное копирование полей (а не копирование всей памяти), с использованием *прямой инициализации*.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization:

> The effects of direct initialization are:
>
> - If `T` is a class type [...]
> - Otherwise, if `T` is a non-class type, standard conversions are used, if necessary, to convert the value of other to the cv-unqualified version of `T`.

В нашем случае, указатель будет просто скопирован, так как у них совместимые типы.